Generalized convex polygon sampling pattern?
There is a pattern used in FEM analysis to generate samples in a square triangle.

This can be easily modified to a unit equilateral triangle, where if one wants $n$ samples on one side of the triangle then we start at the top vertex an place one sample. Then move along both edges by $1 / n$ an place one sample on each. Then we move by an additional $1/n$ along the edges, place two samples and place one sample in the middle...
And in general, at stage $i$ we place to samples on each edge at length $i / n$ from the apex, and then place $i - 2$ samples at uniform distances along the line connecting the two samples.
One can do a trivial extension of this method to a square.
Place $n$ samples on one side, then at each row place an additional $n$ samples.
Is there a way to extend this pattern to an arbitrary convex polygon?
